# c# generic function for overloaded methods

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, overloading

I have two methods, FollowForce() and AvoidForce() which are overloaded to accept either a NavObject or a GameObject. Is there a way to simplify the Follow() function to accept both types?

```
public void Follow(NavObject target){ 
        if(isFollowing){Body.AddForce(FollowForce(target));}
        if(isAvoiding){Body.AddForce(AvoidForce(target));}
    }

public void Follow(GameObject target){ 
        if(isFollowing){Body.AddForce(FollowForce(target));}
        if(isAvoiding){Body.AddForce(AvoidForce(target));}
    }
```

I tried the following, but got `cannot convert 'T' expression to type 'NavObject'`:

```
public void Follow <T>(T target){ 
        if(isFollowing){Body.AddForce(FollowForce(target));}
        if(isAvoiding){Body.AddForce(AvoidForce(target));}
    }
```

Comment: Most likely, but we'll need to see what the `NavObject` and `GameObject` objects look like, as well as the `FollowForce` and `AvoidForce` methods.

Comment: You either  need `NavObject` and `GameObject` to inherit from the same base class (then `FollowForce()` and `AvoidForce()` should accept a paramater of the type of the base class). Or you need `NavObject` and `GameObject` to implement the same interface (then `FollowForce()` and `AvoidForce()` should accept a parameter of the interface's type).

Comment: You need to show FollowForce and AvoidForce in your question as a edit. What you want may be possible but it depends on what those methods do. That being said, I would just stick with the overloaded version.

Answer (score 2):

Potentially, you don't even need to use Generics with this. You could also create an interface for your `NavObject` and `GameObject` to implement that contains all of the properties/methods that are needed within your `FollowForce` and `AddForce` methods.

```
public void Follow(IHaveForce target)
{
    if (isFollowing)
    {
        Body.AddForce(FollowForce(target));
    }
    if (isAvoiding)
    {
        Body.AddForce(AvoidForce(target));
    }
}
```

Then your other methods would need to be set up like this:

```
public Force FollowForce(IHaveForce target)
{
    // Do your work...
}

public Force AvoidForce(IHaveForce target)
{
    // Do your work...
}
```

The only reason you would need to utilize Generics would be if you want to enforce the same type throughout. In the minimal scenario you have provided, it doesn't seem as though that's what you need. If you want to use Generics anyway, you can have your Generic type implement `IHaveForce` as well.

Comment: Full disclaimer: I'm a **huge** proponent of Generics, however this is a scenario where they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FollowForce` and `AvoidForce` functions that are accepting `target` as a parameter must also accept type "T"

Answer (score 0):

If your Objects share functionality you should introduce an abstract base class or an interface `TrackedObject` and extend them in your `NavObject` and `GameObject`.
You then can write the following

```
public void Follow(TrackedObject target){ 
    if(isFollowing){Body.AddForce(FollowForce(target));}
    if(isAvoiding){Body.AddForce(AvoidForce(target));}
}
```

Your static functions parameters of `FollowForce` and `AvoidForce` must then also be of type `TrackedObject`